# How to set a Date value to an object's value that could be undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

Short version: I want to write a check that says if this piece of data from the GraphQL query is undefined, set it to 1 week ago. How do I write this in the return in a typescript file? This is what I have been trying:

```
{data?.program?.flagPageVisits?.edges?.[1]?.node?.createdAt === undefined ? (data.program.flagPageVisits.edges.[1].node.createdAt = new Date(moment().subtract("days", 7).format("DD-MMM-YYYY"))) : ""}
```

I created a new table LastPageVisits and I only want to show rows in a table with a red dot if it's a "new" row for the user, meaning it was created since their LastPageVisit. If the value of the (second to last) LastPageVisit is undefined, I want to set it to 1 week ago. How can I write this check in a React/Typescript return function (data is coming from GraphQL query)?

Comment: When I go to set the value, I get an error because the left side of the statement is undefined. I have also tried ```typeof data?.program?.insightFlagPageVisits?.edges?.[1]?.node?.createdAt === "undefined"```

Comment: Why try to do so much in one line of code? Your code would be more manageable as `const node = data?.program?.flagPageVisits?.edges?.[1]?.node` and then use `node?.createdAt`, for example. And pull the assignment out of the ternary condition.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the feedback. typescript is underlining `const` when defining node and saying Expression expected. i also don't think this helps with the undefined question i have. any thoughts on either of these issues?